# Jmeter transaction controller not failing if parent is if condition

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a script that needs to check if "last sample is ok" through all the children, for this I have a **If controller** that is checking that condition for all children, the children are 6 **transaction controllers**.

The problem comes when a request inside one of the transaction controllers fails, the **if controller** does his job and dont let the script flow but it also does not show any of the request inside the transaction controller that was send.
So I cannot see why or which sampler inside the transaction controller failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "View Results Tree" listener to check which transaction is failing. This is helpful for debugging.

[image]

You will get an error if one of the request fail under transaction controller only when you uncheck "Generate parent sample" in transaction controller. If it is check then you will not see any thing in the view result.

[image]

Comment: the request is suppose to fail, the problem is that if you have an if controller as the parent of your transaction controller, with check for all children and the condition is last sample ok, then the failure will not appear in the view results tree

Comment: Updated my answer for the transaction problem. I hope this help.